# Substituto DataRepeater

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

Sempre usei DataRepeater pra colocar meus dados e colocar botões.

Só que no visual studio 2013 ele sumiu.

Como faço pra usá-lo sem baixar o PowerPack?

Ou se tem algo parecido com sua facilidade?

pra fazer algo como isso aqui;
http://www.decolar.com/shop/flights/results/roundtrip/MCZ/SAO/2015-02-02/2015-02-06/1/0/0

alguém sabe um jeito bom?

Comment: Qual Visual studio você está utilizando? Ele deveria ter o repeater.

Comment: È o DataRepeater do WinForms, e não o do ASP.NET.